# A question about convex set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, operator-algebras

I need to prove the closed set $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}_{+}$ is a convex. And let $x$, $y$ be arbitrary given in $C$, I have proved that $1/2(x+y)\in C$. Then does this means $C$ is convex ?

Comment: @DanielFischer The question specifies that the set is closed.

Comment: I forget "the closed" in my first input.... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C$ is a *closed* subset of $\Bbb R_+,$ then it does indeed suffice to prove that $C$ is midpoint-convex. Indeed, suppose that $C$ were *not* convex, so that there exist $x,y\in C$ such that $tx+(1-t)y\notin C$ for some $0<t<1$. Without loss of generality, suppose that $x<y,$ and put $z=tx+(1-t)y$, so that $x<z<y.$ Since the complement of $C$ is open and $x,y\in C,$ then $z$ lies in some open interval $(a,b)$ disjoint from $C$ with $a,b\in C.$ (Why?) But then $\frac{a+b}2\notin C,$ so $C$ is not midpoint-convex. Thus, midpoint-convex implies convex by contrapositive (convex of course implies midpoint-convex).

Now, it's worth noting that *not all* closed subsets of $\Bbb R_+$ will be (midpoint-)convex. Consider $\{1,2\},$ for example. Given that, I must assume that one of the following is true:

1. You've been given a particular closed set $C$ that you just haven't specified.
2. You've been told that $C$ is an arbitrary closed subset of $\Bbb R_+,$ asked to prove or disprove that it is convex, and made a mistake in your "proof" of midpoint-convexity.
3. You've been given an arbitrary closed midpoint-convex set, and asked to prove that it is convex.

In the first case, there's no problem, since midpoint-convex implies convex for closed subsets of $\Bbb R_+$ using the proof outlined above. In the second case, just use the above counterexample (and take a good hard look at your "proof" to see where you went wrong). In the third case, you need only complete the proof outlined above.

Comment: You said that "$z$ lies in some open interval $(a,b)$ disjoint from $C$ with a,b∈C." It is easy to find an open interval disjoint from $C$, but how can we find $(a,b)$ such that $a, b\in C$?

Comment: **Hint**: Consider the union of all open intervals $(c,d)$ disjoint from $C$ such that $z\in(c,d).$

Comment: So the key point is "closed". We can replace the $\mathbb{R_{+}}$ by $\mathbb{R}$, the conclusion is still correct?

Comment: Absolutely. In fact, we can replace $\Bbb R_+$ by *any* connected subset of $\Bbb R$, and be just fine.

Comment: So the key point is "closed". Thanks Cameron Buie~ :)

Comment: Connectedness is also a key point. For example, we can't replace $\Bbb R_+$ with $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ and get the same conclusion. You are very welcome, though. Feel free to "accept" my answer by clicking the check mark on my post. Welcome to math.SE!